# Windows phone long list selector

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, longlistselector

i have a long list selector that contains a check box in each list box item.

the long list selector is binded to a list that contain the name the image and the status

I want to check or uncheck the check box depending on the status of the field.

I have done a lot of search and I am not able to achieve this please help.

XAML :

```
<phone:LongListSelector x:Name="lstBoxRates" Margin="0,27,-12,0" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" Height="16776941" SelectionChanged="MainLongListSelector_SelectionChanged">
   <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,0,17">
                                <Image Width="54" Height="54">
                                    <Image.Source>
                                        <BitmapImage UriSource="{Binding LocalPath}" />
                                    </Image.Source>
                                </Image>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding name}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}"/>
                                <CheckBox x:Name="LBCheckBox" Content="{Binding LineOne}" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" Height="75" Width="412" Checked="CheckBox_Checked" Unchecked="CheckBox_Unchecked" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
 </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
</phone:LongListSelector>
```

C#:

```
        cView = new CViewModel(AppResources.DBConnectionString);
        List<UBCars> ubc = cView.GetAllCars();

        lstBoxRates.ItemsSource = ubc;
```

Comment: share the code, how your longlistselector xaml and list are !!

Comment: done the code has been added

Comment: Add the XAML code also. We need to see the binding.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and it works after making these changes:

1. Removed the ItemsSource binding in xaml. No point in setting it twice
2. Use properties, not fields, in your model (the UBCars class).